Transform a 3D surface mesh
I have a 3D surface mesh of a proximal femur in a .stl format.
The stl can be downloaded here
https://filesender.renater.fr/?s=download&token=a94a01f4-4710-4643-9003-c3c56a6b38b6
I would like to transform such a geometry by modifying specific key parameters such as the total length of the femut, the femoral head radius, the diaphysis length and its radius and others if possible.
So far I have been able to only modify the total and diaphysis length.
Is there a way mathematica can randomly transform a 3D geometry?
This is the code I have use so far
femurMesh = Import["path/file.stl", "MeshRegion"];

(*Step 3:Identify key points*)
(*Topmost and bottommost points \
(approximate total length)*)

topmostPoint = MaximalBy[meshCoordinates, Last][[1]];
bottommostPoint = MinimalBy[meshCoordinates, Last][[1]];

(*Total length of the femur*)

totalLength = Norm[topmostPoint - bottommostPoint];

(*Approximate diaphysis length (assume a percentage of total  length)*)\
diaphysisLengthRatio = 0.6;(*Approximate proportion of the \
diaphysis*)diaphysisLength = totalLength*diaphysisLengthRatio;

(*Step 4:Define transformation parameters*)
totalLengthFactor = \
1.1;(*Scale factor for total length*)diaphysisLengthFactor = \
1.1;(*Scale factor for diaphysis length*)(*Calculate scaling \
transformations*)(*Total length   transformation*)scaledTotalLength = 
ScalingTransform[{1, 1, totalLengthFactor}, bottommostPoint];

(*Diaphysis length transformation*)

scaledDiaphysisLength = 
ScalingTransform[{1, 1, diaphysisLengthFactor}, 
Mean[{bottommostPoint, 
 bottommostPoint + 
  diaphysisLengthFactor*(topmostPoint - bottommostPoint)}]];

(*Combine transformations (applied sequentially)*)

combinedTransformation = 
Composition[scaledTotalLength, scaledDiaphysisLength];

(*Apply transformations to the mesh*)

transformedCoordinates = combinedTransformation /@meshCoordinates;
transformedFemur = 
MeshRegion[transformedCoordinates, MeshCells[femurMesh, 2]];      

(*Step 5:Visualize the transformed femur*)
Show[{femurMesh}, 
Axes -> True, Boxed -> False, PlotRange -> All, 
PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}]


Might want to show the code you used to get the operations that were successful. (On a related note, I have orthopedists in the family, but usually they operate directly on femurs rather than scanned images thereof.)

What do you mean 'they operate directly on femur' ? the .stl surface mesh has been obtained from CTscans and further segmentation.

Just kidding around. Orthopedists operate on bones, whereas image processing experts operate on scans of bones.
